# Choosing the right Lucene Directory

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

There are many kind of directory types that can be used to build a Lucene index. Which one is best suited to improve search speed on a RedHat machine (not sure if the OS is relevant or not)?

- `RAMDirectory` - Cannot use, index is too big
- `SimpleFSDirectory` - Cannot be this one because it's 'Simple'...
- `MMapDirectory` - Maybe this one?
- `NIOFSDirectory` - Or this one?
- `Any better options?`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason to pick one over the others, I'd recommend simply calling [`FSDirectory.open(File)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html).  This allows Lucene to make the decision on which implementation is ideal.

For the curious, here is how the decision is made:

```
public static FSDirectory open(File path, LockFactory lockFactory) throws IOException {
  if ((Constants.WINDOWS || Constants.SUN_OS || Constants.LINUX)
        && Constants.JRE_IS_64BIT && MMapDirectory.UNMAP_SUPPORTED) {
    return new MMapDirectory(path, lockFactory);
  } else if (Constants.WINDOWS) {
    return new SimpleFSDirectory(path, lockFactory);
  } else {
    return new NIOFSDirectory(path, lockFactory);
  }
}
```

If you want to try to be surer about getting the ideal pick than that, I can only recommend trying them and profiling, to see which provides the best performance.

Comment: nice! and I believe that I'll have to do the same thing when I create the index, right?

Comment: Yes, a directory can be opened the same way when creating or replacing an index or when opening an existing one.